# Apple IPv6 - server connectivity issue

Tags: ipv6

We are dealing in these day with issue, that our application cannot reach our server. The application was approved by apple, where testing server was miwe-api-demo.netbrick.cz. The production server address is api.mive.de and we are not able to connect to this server with already approved app. However with release candidate we are able to connect to both servers – testing and production as well. Production server is running on IPv4. Is Apple changing somehow application during approval process in that way IPv4 is not supported after review? Please note that our servers are:
Testing - https://miwe-api-demo.netbrick.cz
Production: https://api.mive.de

Answer (score 1):

Your server named miwe-api-demo.netbrick.cz has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in the DNS, but api.mive.de doesn't have any IP addresses, either IPv4 or IPv6. (Though strangely it has an MX record...This is probably also a mistake.)

To resolve the problem, add the appropriate A and AAAA records for api.mive.de.

Comment: We are dealing with some DNS configuration issue right now, but this was not the case in the past. I will let you know once this will be fixed to continue with analysing.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for your feedback. We also found DNS errors and we fixed them already. But this is not the case I believe, please note this case.
As usual before any application we send for apple review, we are reviewing release candidate internally in our company. Release candidate can connect to server api.miwe.de (production) and miwe-api-demo.netbrick.cz (demo), both successfully, that is our conclusion....

Comment: As a next step we built production version (same code without any change) with all necessary apple profiles, we sent this application for review, where review is passed successful as well on server miwe-api-demo.netbrick.cz. We downloaded application from iTunes and suddenly api.miwe.de is not reachable from the app.
...

Comment: So my question is, what is the difference between release candidate and reviewed application in iTunes. Apple also did review for the same application trying connect to api.miwe.de, where the feedback was apple is running only IPv6 network. With that information we prepared demo server miwe-api-demo.netbrick.cz supporting dual networking IPv4 and IPv6 and with the same setup we prepared production server api.miwe.de.
...

Comment: Now I want to investigate difference between RC and Production application which has been reviewed by apple, also for our future project.
Thank you in advance

Comment: @JanMotyčák Is your production endpoint api.mive.de or api.miwe.de? You have said both at different times here.

Comment: Please note, that I had written wrong server doman, original is api.miwe.de

Answer (score 1):

Use CloudFlare DNS to resolve the issue without migrating or moving current server.